# Auto Suggested Text Box in JSP Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, textbox, autosuggest

I am creating one application in which i am using jsp/servlet..

I want to implement auto suggestion text box for user. The suggested data should come from database.

can anyone help me that how should i implement it.I mean should i use javascript or write some function in jsp.

Any help would be appropriated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jqueryui autcomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) to handle the client javascript side.  You will have to write something server side that returns some Json from your database.

You could use [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to provide the Json support from your java server.  XStream started as an xml serialiser but now supports Json as part of its alternative output formats.